# Inverse map from SO(n) to $\mathfrak{so}(n)$

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

The Lie algebra $\mathfrak{so}(n)$ of the Lie group $SO(n)$ is the space of real skew-symmetric matrices.

Given an element $U \in SO(n)$, how can I get back the element $\mathfrak{u} \in \mathfrak{so}(n)$ such that $\exp(\mathfrak{u}) = U$.

I tried matrix logarithm,

$$\log(U) = P\log(D)P^{-1}$$

but it doesn't work for the example below:

$$U = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$

By diagonalization, I computed

$$P = \frac{1}{\sqrt2}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} ; \quad D = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}$$

Then I take the $\log$ of the diagonal matrix.

$$\log(D) = \begin{pmatrix} \mathbf{0} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \mathbf{i\pi} & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \mathbf{0} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \mathbf{i\pi} \end{pmatrix} $$

Finally, using the formula above $\log(U) = P \log(D)P^{-1}$,

$$\log(U) = \frac{1}{\sqrt2}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} \mathbf{0} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \mathbf{i\pi} & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \mathbf{0} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \mathbf{i\pi} \end{pmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt2} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

which gives

$$\log(U) = \frac{i\pi}{2}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 1 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$

But this matrix is neither real nor skew-symmetric, so how can it be can element of $\mathfrak{so}(n)$

Comment: While $\exp$ in this case is surjective, it is definitely not injective so there is no single inverse. We could define a right inverse but we have to make some choices. The first step might to consider when $\exp X = \exp Y$ happens